# iOS: why can't I access a @property from a global Block (outside of method)

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, objective-c-blocks, block

I'm trying to create a global block that can be used from any method. I want this block to access @properties of the class. But when I try to do this I get "use of undeclared identifier self" accessing the backing variables _myVar also doesn't work.

Why doesn't this work? And what work around would give me a block that I can access from any method? Thanks.

An example:

```
@interface myClass()
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL subjectSex;
@end

@implementation

// these returns will get: use of undeclared identifier
int (^myBlock) = ^{

   if(self.subjectSex) return 1;  
   return (!_subjectSex);

}

@end
```

Comment: Cause property is an Instance variable, not a class one. As a Workaround you can create a singleton with properties or create class variable with class accessors.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you **showed your actual code**.

Comment: What object do you expect `self` to be here?

Comment: Pass in self as a parameter to the block

Answer (score 2):

You must define the block inside an instance method. You can then have a static block pointer that all your methods can access. When you assign the block to the pointer you must copy it:

```
s_blockPtr = [block copy];
```

Alternatively, you can send the this pointer as argument to the block. It's simpler to understand but may be more typing.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't so much have to do with property access as that you are using `self`. (You can use properties of other objects that you have access to without problem.) `self` does not exist in that scope. `self` is an implicit parameter in *methods*. Since your block definition is not inside a method, there is no variable named `self` (unless you define a global variable named `self`, but that would probably be a bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are nothing it's just a function pointer.If you want to access property in block you have to explicitly set __block in the property i.e.
you have to tell the compiler this is a block type property.
Let's take a closure look on blocks:
suppose there are two threads T1 and T2

```
  //T1 Thread
    void fun(int (*funptr)(int a,int b))
    {
       funptr(2,3);  
    }

    //T2 Thread
    int add(int a,int b)
{
     return a+b;
}
//Main Thread

    fun(&add);
    printf("Hello");
```

From the above code ,assume main thread address is 20004 and executing fun having address 20006 and that fun taking function pointer as an argument which pointing to another function of thread T2 at an address of 20064 which means context switching from Thread T1 and T2, while executing T2 thread,function don't know about the global variables which are in code segment thats why they can't access because they are in different thread and this is the reason blocks are running on different thread.
that's solve.

Answer (score -3):

You can access any object in a block by declaring it block type

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain) __block NSString *strName;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^(void)
   {
      self.strName= @"XYZ";
   });
```

Comment: The `__block` storage type is only there to tell the compiler how the capturing of the variable should be done (ie. if it should be mutable or if it should be copied).